# Printing the code of the file

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("my file.txt", "w");
    int n = 5;
    fprintf(f, "n equals to %d", n);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("my file2.txt", "w");
    char *txt = "New file";
    fwrite(txt, 1, strlen(txt), f);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("my file3.txt", "w");
    char *txt2 = "Hello";
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(txt2); i++)
    {
        printf("Mouse cursor at %d.\n", ftell(f));
        fputc(txt2[i], f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    char str[1024];
    while (!feof(f))
    {
    fscanf(f, "%s", str);
    puts(str);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    long size = fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, f);
    puts(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Take a look in this part of the code :

```
f = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
long size = fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
fread(buffer, 1, size, f);
puts(buffer);
free(buffer);
fclose(f);
```

I've tried to print the code in my file and this is what I wrote to do it ^
When I try to print it with puts function it prints 3 characters :
http://i61.tinypic.com/ortdvl.png

The third character is changing in each execution.
Anyway to the question, I don't know why this happens can someone explain me what I did wrong ?

Comment: fseek() doesn't return anything useful except a success/failure indication. Either you seeked to the specified location, or you didn't. If you want to get the size of the file, then seek to the end then use ftell(), or stat() the file and get size data from there.

Comment: And `ftell` doesn't return the mouse cursor position.

Comment: I know it doesnt return the mouse cursor x, y I meant it returns like the number of character index ? or how ever you can say that

Comment: You don't check the return value of `fopen`. What if it returned `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(f);
char *buffer = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
rewind(f);
fread(buffer, 1, size, f);
```

Comment: return of fseek, success is 0, other not 0.